# Can git with git-lfs push `lfs` to git without git-lfs?

Tags: git

`dev pc` is `centos 7`,with `git 1.8.3.1`,`git-lfs/2.4.2`.I use git-lfs to track `*.png`.
`production server 192.168.56.112` is `centos 7` with `git 1.8.3.1`,without `git-lfs`.

When I `git push production master` from `dev pc` to `production server` bare repo, I cannot find any `.png` file in `production server`.

I am not sure whether  `git with git-lfs` can transfer `.png` files to `git without git-lfs`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `LFS` there probably are no `.png` files, to begin with ...

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: @kittygirl unless you have a LFS client *&* server, the client is merely useless by itself, because those text pointers will never resolve. here it's explained: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLR1RNqJ1Mw

Comment: My `dev pc` is LFS client, cloned from Gitlab git repo.

Comment: @kittygirl the one at `192.168.56.112` most likely would need `LFS` server installed - and a remote storage facility configured. because as soon as the client starts tracking a file-type, it won't check in those files, but attempts to check in text pointers - which cannot be handled, while there is no server.